# How to count rows of text based on certain endings of words in the text

Tags: python, pandas, text

I am trying to count the number of rows in my data frame that contains the words/letters 'red' in some form as a separate word or part of a word.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [10, 46, 75, 12, 99],
                   'text': [['The blurred vision is no good'],         
                            ['start', '15', 'tag', '#redding'],
                            [],
                            ['The books were blue instead'],
                            ['Red is the new Black ']
                            ]
                    })
```

The output should count rows 0, 1, and 4, i.e., count=3.

I tried the following code:

```
df['text'].str.contains(r'[a-zA-Z]red+', na=False).sum()
```

But it doesn't work. I would be extremely grateful if someone could help me fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use `any` in a list comprehension to check if the string `"red"` appears in any string in a sublist:

```
out = sum(any(True for x in lst if 'red' in x.lower()) for lst in df['text'])
```

Output:

```
3
```

Answer (score 1):

Since there are lists of strings in the "text" column, I'll first join those individual strings with a space.

Then, I lowercase the strings for case-insensitive matching, and finally use `contains` on the whole concatenated string. Any occurrence of "red" in one form of another will be easily filtered this way:

```
>>> df['text'].str.join(" ").str.lower().str.contains('red')
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
Name: text, dtype: bool
```

and for the count of rows:

```
>>> df['text'].str.join(" ").str.lower().str.contains('red').sum()
3
```